# SAMD09 Debug port connection issue

Tags: atmel, debugging, swd, cortex-m0, cortex-m0+

I have recently built a board using an ATSAMD09D14A-MUT, today it came the time to test it, however problems arose in a strangely annoying manner, when trying to connect to the device i get error 4109 (no device detected), [image: Schematic sensor relevant to the uC]

As you can see in the following schematics the setup is quite standard, the only things that can be considered somewhat odd are the pull up resistors (they are quite high in value) and the absence of an oscillator, since it the timing precision required for this application didn't require one.

the steps i took to try solving this issue are the following:

1: reduce the swd frequency down to 32khz

2: change the resistors from 100k down to 50k

3: change the reset resistor to 10k assuming there may be noise in the line

4: build a second programming cable to eliminate that possibility

the result was the same after these steps
also, the device was externally powered (i know ice doesn't supply power)

i would really appreciate any help with this since i pretty much eliminated all the possibilities i could think of

Edit:
The cable used to connect the device is as follows

Header    ICE

pin 1 <-> pin 2

pin 2 <-> pin 4

pin 3 <-> pin 3

pin 4 <-> pin 1

pin 5 <-> pin 10

Comment: What do you connect to the 5 pin header? Are you able to measure the 3v3 and the reset line?

Comment: An adapter for a standard 10 pin arm debug probe, 


pin 1 <-> pin 2 (ice), pin 2<-> pin 4, pin 3 <-> pin 3, pin 4<-> pin 1, pin 5 <-> pin 10

Comment: Basically I'd say that looks ok. I don't think it's a resistor problem since SWDIO/SWCLK are driven signals during debug. Does you debugger detect the correct voltage?

Comment: yes, around 3.6v, it is really annoying not to have an oscilloscope at hand

Comment: Seems a bit high to me. Can you confirm that's your intention? Because you're operating near the end of the spec.

Comment: With the 100k i'm operating at the edge of the spectrum essentially, that's why one of the tests was to reduce the resistance by half, maybe ill try reducing it to ten later, those values were intended to keep energy consumption at an absolute minimum since this device is intended to be battery operated

Comment: I meant the 3.6V ...

Comment: oh yeah, its a little high, however that is still in the operating range, the absolute maximum is about 4 if im not wrong

Comment: 3.63 according to the datasheet. Try supplying it with a stable 3.3V

Comment: i will, ill let you know the results

Comment: well, i hadn't got a 3v3 power supply, so i used 2 AA batteries, in this case the voltage was 2.9, which is well within the operating range, the result however was the same

Comment: Which programmer are you using?

Comment: Atmel ice with latest firmware

Comment: Sorry, out of luck here. I'd say it's the debugger pinout which doesn't match. Schematic seems correct to me

Comment: i'm starting to doubt the debugger at this point, not its pinout, i've used it tons of times, but whether this particular one is faulty, i've connected the supply that on the debugger indicated 3.6v, when measuring with a multimeter i get 3.28

Comment: **1.** `Edit` your question to show **full reproducible physical wiring details** of the SWD connection between the board and the programmer.  Beware that the Atmel SWD probes tend to have a pin assignment that is backwards from the usual physical numbering of a connector relative to its physical index, and so are typically used with a cable having one connector crimped on the wrong way around.  **2.** What definite evidence do you have that the MCU can operate without an external oscillator?  **3.** Monitor the SWD lines with a scope for activity

Comment: 2: the mcu has a 32k internal oscillator and an 8mhz one, and 3: i don't have a scope here, that would make things a lot easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the winner is: Chris Stratton
you were right in point 1:
the atmel debugger has the pinout inverted, now that i remember, i had to deal with that about 2 years ago, however since in most boards i use 10 pin cables that i had already made i forgot about this issue, its working properly now

Comment: Glad to hear it's working.  Your edit to the question doesn't really capture the physical reality of the wiring - you list what you believe the pin numbers to be, but you don't really document the wiring in a way that someone could have used to determine that the physical connections were wrong.  So we're left with guessing - luckily that worked.  But it's not really how this site is supposed to be used.

Comment: i think it does chris, thats exactly how the wiring is, the pins match the standard 10 pin arm debugger and the standard numbering of an idc flat connector, the thing is that for some reason atmel got it completely backwards as you point out

Comment: The fact that one can't tell from your question that it is backwards is exactly the **physical wiring detail** that is missing from your question.  You supplied only *logical* documentation, not *physical*.